# phpmailer complications for spam filters "-f"

Tags: php, smtp, phpmailer, email-headers, envelope

My clients hosting service isn't accepting emails sent from the website that doesn't have "-f" at the start of the FROM address. This related to a recent outgoing SPAM filter they added.

Official response is:

> “senders envelope of data” is missing certain elements

I use phpmailer, everything was working fine until now using SMTP authentication.

But now with phpmailer, this DOESN'T work

```
$mail->From         = 'me@test.com';
```

Also doesn't work

```
$mail->From         = '-f me@test.com';
```

Its invalid obviousdly, not a good looking email address.

I CAN get mail to actually send like this:

```
mail('me@test.com', 'the subject', 'the message', null, '-f me@test.com');
```

But that isn't phpmailer, this is the garden variety php function. So im trying to make PHPmailer add "-f " to the FROM automatically somehow.

Should I be adjusting the class files to somehow get around that? Stuck!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You've got your transports mixed up. `-f` in the `mail()` function is an additional parameter passed to the underlying sendmail binary that sets the envelope sender of the message (and officially it should not have a space after it, like `-fme@test.com`). However, it does not apply when you are sending via SMTP because you get control over that parameter with the `Sender` property. You should do this:

```
$mail->Sender = 'me@test.com';
```

If you send using SMTP it will use that as the envelope sender (as the content of the SMTP `MAIL FROM` command), and if you send via `isMail()` or `isSendmail()` transports, it will set the sender via the -f property.

Also make sure you're using the latest PHPMailer from GitHub.

Comment: can you point me to any documentation i can get on isMail() and isSendmail()? I have been not using these, but mail still sends - not really sure what the implications are for those settings.

Comment: API docs on those are [here](http://phpmailer.github.io/PHPMailer/classes/PHPMailer.html#method_isMail), but there's not much to them - they are much less complex than `isSMTP()`, but you can see in the source code [here](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/blob/master/class.phpmailer.php#L1163) and [here](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/blob/master/class.phpmailer.php#L1097) that they both make use of the `-f` param with the `Sender` property.